# PHP PDO iterating Associative Array returning errors

Tags: php, pdo

I need to Iterate through an Associative array that's being generated from PHP PDO.

**PDO:**

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT setting, setting_value FROM app_config")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Array output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [setting] => site_title
            [setting_value] => My Website
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [setting] => site_desc
            [setting_value] => Description of my website
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [setting] => batch
            [setting_value] => 2022-23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [setting] => session_start
            [setting_value] => 01-April-2022
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [setting] => session_end
            [setting_value] => 01-March-2023
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [setting] => site_mode
            [setting_value] => development
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [setting] => copyright
            [setting_value] => All rights reserved
        )

)
```

**I have tried:**

```
foreach ($stmt as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<p>$key = $value</p>";
}
```

**its returning errors:**

> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 0 = Array
>
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 1 = Array
>
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 2 = Array
>
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 3 = Array
>
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 4 = Array
>
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 5 = Array
>
> Warning: Array to string conversion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\app\config\config.php on line 58 6 = Array

**Also tried nested loop:**

```
foreach ($stmt as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($key as $result) {
      echo '<pre>'. $value .' : '. $result . '</pre>';
  }
}
```

Comment: `$stmt` is an array of arrays. You can think of it as an array of all _rows_ in your resultset. In your foreach, think of `$key` as the row number (starting from 0) and `$value` as an array of all _columns_ in that particular row. Does that help clarify where you’re going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path with the nested loop, but in the outer loop you don't need to worry about the key, only the inner loop:

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        'setting' => 'site_title',
        'setting_value' => 'My Website'
    ],
    [
        'setting' => 'site_desc',
        'setting_value' => 'Description of my website'
    ],
    [
        'setting' => 'batch',
        'setting_value' => '2022-23'
    ]
];

foreach ($data as $record) {
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' => ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
setting => site_title
setting_value => My Website

setting => site_desc
setting_value => Description of my website

setting => batch
setting_value => 2022-23
```

Comment: One another question though, how do i store all the `setting` with `setting_value` in a session? i have done this way `$_SESSION[$key] = [$value];` is it correct way?

Comment: Very close, `$_SESSION[$key] = $value`, doing it your way will wrap `$value` inside an array.

Comment: How can i access a particular value from session? For example i want to get `site_title` its not working. throwing errors. Warning: Undefined array key "site_title"

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION)` where you want to access a particular value to double check what session variables are set. Is `session_start()` at the beginning of each file?